# Why does `[].to_s.empty?` behave differently between ruby 1.9 and 2.0?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, ruby-2.0

This was the behaviour in 1.9 ruby:

```
[].to_s.empty? #=> false
{}.to_s.empty? #=> false
[].to_s #=> "[]"
{}.to_s #=> "{}"
[43,43].to_s #=> "[43, 43]"
{"fire"=>"water"}.to_s #=> "{\"fire\"=>\"water\"}"
```

This is the behaviour in 2.0 ruby:

```
[].to_s.empty? #=> true
{}.to_s.empty? #=> true
[].to_s #=> ""
{}.to_s #=> ""
[43,43].to_s #=> "4343"
{"fire"=>"water"}.to_s #=> "firewater"
```

I am wondering about this change in behaviour for `to_s` method in 2.0.

Edit: My apologies. I am closing this question. For some reason I thought I was running 2.x.x ruby but the path was messed up. It pointed to 1.8.7 version of ruby that was on the image. When I fixed the path to point at the right ruby (2.1.4) I see the right behaviour.

Comment: It is not a correct behavior. 2.0 should behave exactly the same as 1.9.3. Check if you don't have any extensions loaded to ruby or irb.

Comment: specifically what build of 1.9 are you testing with?

Comment: `[].to_s` is `'[]'` in 2.2, 2.1, 2.0, and 1.9.3 so none of them should say that `[].to_s` is empty. Your `[43,43].to_s` and `{"fire"=>"water"}.to_s` are also bizarre in 2.0.x so what is messing with your `to_s` methods?

Comment: And what is the `x` in `2.0.x`? Was there a `to_s` regression to 1.8.7 behavior somewhere? Are you certain that you're using 2.0.x rather than 1.8.7? 1.8.7 gives exactly the results you're claiming for 2.0.x.

Comment: That doesn't look right at all. What does `RUBY_VERSION` yield for the 2.0.x test?

Comment: In Ruby 2.0 `to_s` has been changed to an alias of inspect. The only change this has made that I know of is when calling `to_s` on an `Array` in 1.9.3 it will return the `to_s` method(s) of the objects contained within but in 2.0 it will return the `inspect` of these objects. e.g. `class Frog; def to_s "monkey" end; end`. In 1.9.3. `[Frog.new].to_s #=> "[monkey]"` and in 2.0 `[Frog.new].to_s #=> "[#<Frog:0x00000002f28828>]"` but I cannot reproduce what you are showing as others have stated. So unless `Array#to_s` and `Hash#to_s` have been redefined to empty strings your findings are off.

Comment: It makes your question complicated to use `empty?`. You should compare results like `[].to_s`, `{}.to_s` without `empty?`. That would make the question clearer.

Answer (score 1):

In 2.x, this is the output of `[].to_s`

```
2.1.5 :001 > [].to_s
 => "[]"
2.1.5 :002 > [43,43].to_s
 => "[43, 43]"
```

Given that it doesn't match your Ruby setup, there is definitely something that is changing it in your system.

Try to start a simple, clear `irb` session. If it works like I have shown above, it means there is something wrong in your Ruby app.

If it doesn't work, it means there is something wrong in your Ruby setup.

Regardless of where the problem is, I wonder why you are relying on a code like

```
[].to_s.empty?
```

I can't find a single case where the code above would ever make sense. If you want to check the presence of some item in the array, simply use

```
[].empty?
```

If you want to treat the array as string, convert it using a possible reasonable approach, such as `join`

```
[].join("").empty?
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The machine I was working on had a messed up environment path and was actually pointing at a very old version of ruby (1.8.7).